# What alcoholic drinks would my people make?

Tags: ancient-history, forestry, alcoholic-beverages

In 280 BC a Gaulish tribe became stranded in a forest with no access to grains/potatoes/cultivated grapes. (Magic handwavy - no access to anybody else or land that isn't a forest). They have fresh water from a river.

The forest can be populated with any plants that might be found in Europe at that time. It has been 2000 years and technology has not changed much, although with magic they can heat or cool large volumes of liquid to precise temperatures.

What alcoholic beverages would they make? I am looking for something more creative than Cider/Mead. 2000 years is a long time.

For info:

- They would have a good knowledge of Greek and Roman drinks (inc. wine, mead and cider)
- They have are capable craftsmen
- They have sources of metal tools/equipment if required - to Roman tech levels
- The entirety of the drink has to come from plants found in mixed forests
- The magical ability is rare and so only small quantities of drink can be produced if using that method.
- A variety of drinks with different strengths would be a better answer
- A very good answer would show some creativity in the different plant options availible.

Comment: Wild grapes were plentiful enough to make some wine. Riparian grapes (non-domesticated) should be sufficient for the task. Potatoes are a new world crop, unavailable in Europe before the 1500s (not sure the exact date).

Comment: I understood Riparian grapes are native to North America and so wouldn't be present in Europe at the time. I hadn't thought about wild grape strains in Europe. Thanks.

Comment: It might be quicker to ask what fruits/grains/foodstuffs have _not_ been made into alcohol by humans over the past 2000 years! Fermentation is not difficult and would be a well known process around 300BC, distillation is not technically complicated either and was recorded in multiple places in the early centuries AD; magic temperature control would certainly accelerate that.

Comment: No potatoes? I certainly hope so. If these Gauls did have access to potatoes, it means they've wondered over to the Americas around 18-ish centuries before the rest of Europe saw this plant.

Comment: **anything** that is based on Sugar OR Starch can be made into booze, easily. Even Tree Sap. With a lot of effort, even cellulose fibers(wood!!) can be turned into booze. You just need to have your chemistry exactly right, else you make methanol instead of ethanol.

Comment: In order to get the question reopened, you would need to be specific about the resources available.

Comment: Artemisia absinthium will be their friend! It is widely used in the preparation of a number of alcoholic beverages (including Absinthe obviously). It will enrich the drinks others have posted in their answers. Aside flavouring and preparing bitters and vermouths it will double up in the preparation of medicines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make "some sort" of alcoholic beverage with *anything" starchy or or having high sugar content.

Vodka is made from cereal.

You can make wine/cider with *any* kind of fruit.

Mead is essentially fermented honey.

You can make alcohol from refined sugar (an expensive way, but you can).

Distillation is only needed to concentrate alcohol above natural endurance of given yeast (about 20%). This technique was well known in Roman times, but was *not* applied to wine (they had very different tastes: usually they drank watered and sweetened wine; drinking it straight was for barbarians; no wonder they did not like superalcoholics).

Comment: You also have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumis, which is made from milk (usually mare or donkey's milk).

Answer (score 7):

Potatoes, cereals and grapes are not the only sources for making alcoholic beverages.

[Cider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cider) can be done by fermenting juices of apples, pears, blueberries and any other fruit which has enough sugar in it.

Even mixing honey with water and letting it fermenting can be used to make [mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mead).

Comment: Thanks. They definitely knew about cider, but I was hoping for some more variety with different strengths that might be used for different events, from the day-to-day to special events.

Comment: you can distill the fermented fruits and vegetables into stronger drinks

Comment: My understanding is that distillation was unknown to the Romans for another couple of hundred years.

Comment: 1200 bce I believe is earliest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distillation#History

Comment: Thanks. It is possible the Gauls would have known about it then.

Comment: Not recorded in Europe until about 900 AD (thus a comment not an answer), but maybe you can take liberties with the timeline and include [Birch and Maple sap drinks](https://www.chelseagreen.com/2020/sap-syrup-beer-wine-liquor/) (beware commercial link).

Comment: Thank you Rogue Ant. That is what I am after. Specific, less obvious drinks. The time line may not match the real world but trapped in a forest for generations would lead to advances in this area.

Comment: You can use the applejack method and let freezing temperatures concentrate your alcohol. let it partially freeze, fish out the ice, which reduces the water content.

Answer (score 3):

List of things yo can make alcohol from.

In order of how easy it is to do.

**Honey**, I do this myself, breathtakingly easy.

**Fruit**, basically any fruit that tastes sweet will work, great way to use up unripe or overripe fruit.

**starchy tubers**, cook them first to detoxify.

**Nuts**, specifically chestnuts or any other very starchy nut.  less starchy nuts like acorns can be used to make mild "beers"

**tree sap**, a lot of work though, you have to concentrate it first.

Some **mushrooms** can even be fermented.

Even **artichokes**, **onions**, and **herbs** like anise and cloves have been used.

If it has enough sugar in it, you can ferment it.

How much sugar there is in what you use is basically what determines how alcoholic the drink is. You can cut fermentation short to make it weaker which was common.

you can concentrate alcohol using freezing temperatures. Let it start to freeze fish out ice. This is how applejack was made from cider.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific about the tubers? What kind of drink does it make?

Comment: @Hukk2010 Any starchy tuber, you mash them up and ferment them. Basically anything that is only fermented  is a type of "wine" We don't really have a systematic naming convention for alcoholic drinks.  Flavors will vary a lot depending on what you use and how far you let it ferment. Potatoes, manioc, yam, taro, beet, carrot, radish, there are thousands of tubers.

Answer (score 1):

**Acerum**.

It is mysterious why the Amerinds did not ferment maple syrup into alcoholic beverages but apparently they did not.  It can certainly be done!

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acerum

> It was the natives of northeasternNorth America who developed the
> method of turning maple sap into syruplong before the arrival of the
> Europeans. Settlers in New France and New England quickly took up this
> technique and gradually improved it, especially since the mid-20th
> century, developing several products such as maple,maple sugar, maple
> butter,maple caramel and many others.
>
> It was not until the 1970s that some producers began to produce
> alcohol from this syrup. Although some distilled alcohol tests were
> then conducted in university laboratories, it was not until the
> 1990s that some maple syrup producers began to produce a wine based on
> this sweet resource, which would eventually be called Acer.

Your people commune with "forest spirits" (get it? Forest spirits!) by tapping syrup and fermenting it into sweet liquor.  Maple and similar sweet saps form the basis and they are  flavored with other roots and leaves including birch, sassafras, gum and others.

Comment: It takes a lot of work to concentrate sap enough to make something that ferments well.

Comment: @John - but the payoff is a lot better than other things which take comparable work!

Comment: I just meant that's probably why they didn't do it. why go through all that work when there is plenty of fruit and honey around.

Comment: Maybe they just did not much like alcoholic beverages.

Answer (score 1):

Your forest has fruits, right?

Take a bit of
[image]

pulp it, boil it to kill the wrong bugs, seed it and ferment it.
Then feed it through this monstrosity (3 times)
[image]

and you make this:(sorry this image is the watered-down, legal variant. Images of the real thing are a bit troublesome to post)
[image]

Genuine, 190-proof (95% alcohol) Witblits.
Suitable for drinking, and runs fine in your car engine if you add a drop of 2-stroke oil.

Comment: Distillation is fairly advanced for the given tech level.

Answer (score 1):

"Here’s what the Encyclopedia Galáctica has to say about alcohol. It says that alcohol is a colorless volatile liquid formed by the fermentation of sugars and also notes its intoxicating effect on certain carbon-based life forms.

"*The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy* also mentions alcohol. It says that the best drink in existence is the Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster. It says that the effect of drinking a Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster is like having your brains smashed out by a slice of lemon wrapped around a large gold brick.

"The *Guide* also tells you on which planets the best Pan Galactic Gargle Blasters are mixed, how much you can expect to pay for one and what voluntary organizations exist to help you rehabilitate afterwards..."

Thanks, Douglas. Naturally, they would want the best, so they would make the Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster. Plus, it is very simple to make in terms of technology (you just need a spoon and a cup!), and does not require grains/grapes. Only problem is that they were invented on Damogran, a planet around 500,000 light years away, and Ford Prefect wasn't born yet. And possibly getting the tooth of an Algolian Suntiger.